# Difference between not searching a field and doing %" "% search

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, wildcard

This may seem like a silly question at first, but hear me out.

I am currently improving a horrendous searching function (well, multiple all used for one output), and when search for part of an individuals name in a database of ~6000 names, they do where fname LIKE %first_name% and lname LIKE %last_name% and enum LIKE %employee_number%. The problem is, if you don't specify a first name, last name, or employee number, the search, instead of just not specifying these fields in the WHERE search, they just pass the blank strings retrieved from the names input (Ex. fname LIKE %""% and lname LIKE %""% and enum LIKE %""%.

I'm super new to SQ performance, more of a logical web dev, and I was just curious how much of a strain this would have on speed and efficiency as opposed to just not including those fields as a specification in the search if they are empty.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you asking if it is better to dynamically choose (or not choose) the columns vs choosing all columns and passing blank strings in your where clause?

Comment: Yeah I'm more so asking if it would be worth it to write a new query if the user enters no values at all for first name last name and employee number that does the same search but doesn't condition the search on first, last and emp num at all, or leave it so it passes the blank "" into the already exisiting query which will result in it to get it's results where first_name = %""% and last_name = %""% and employee_number = %""%

Comment: Is the SQL currently working at all? `select where lname = ""` is only going to return rows where the lastname is an empty string, it's not going to "skip" that check.

Comment: I'm almost certain it would be better to leave those parameters out of the where clause if they are blank, but it would just be a lot of time investing, as these queries are massive, and are connected to a lot in the back end, or if throwing a blank string into a leading and trailing wildcard condition isn't horrible on performance

Comment: shoot I'm so sorry, I've been meaning fname, lname, enum LIKE %""%, not =

Comment: Well not querying a column is certainly going to be better performance than using LIKE. But your table only has 6000 rows? Are you sure this is the performance bottleneck?

Comment: Also, it is retrieving documents and files associated with those people, and there are about 400,000+ of those documents

Comment: and the bigger one I'm tackling after this has 2.2 million documents and files

Comment: It is usually a terrible idea to use two `%`, anyway.  For most searches, anchoring the search on the left, using only a `%` on the right of the search term is sufficient, and *far* more efficient.  `LIKE 'Fre%'` and `LIKE '%Fre%'` will both find 'Fred' but only the former will actually stand any chance of using an available index.  That is how databases work.  Using a leading `%` is a killer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will take longer to search when including the empty fields than with not - unless the SQL engine is really smart enough to say '"%" matches everything, lets ignore it', which I doubt.

The real question you are asking is how much -- and that one can't be answered for you - only you can do that through performance testing. Try with and without it and compare the results - you don't need SO for that.

However, I would generally say this. Since you sometimes search for those fields anyway, they should likely be indexed - perhaps even a compound indexed. Once indexed, a search on 6k records is trivial. The performance difference between with and without the empty fields probably becomes not worth your effort and you move on to more important things.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, thanks! Sorry my question wasn't super descriptive, I'm new to stack overflow question formats as well and I'm leaving out a lot of information. It's retrieving 2.2 million documents and files from another table, but it's referencing another table to see if its linked to people, getting the count of documents and joining the person table where the last name is like %lname% and so on like I explained above.

Comment: @DavidBond; Np, you are still faced with the performance issue when you use real fields. I assume you cant tolerate a 500ms query with empty fields and a 50s query when you use fields, for example. Do the work on optimizing the search when fields are present. Once you get that one fast enough, the empty field question mostly goes away. In other words, you are asking the wrong question. The question should be "how to I performantly query 2million records when searching over these fields."

Answer (score 0):

There would be a slight performance increase if you excluded the term instead of doing `lname like "%%"` - the query `select null like "%"` returns null, so it does need to do the check for each value for each row.

If you want to speed up this query, I'd recommend adding a [Full Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) Index to the relevant columns.

Answer (score 0):

With ~6000 rows, I think the strain just depends on your hardware and resource availability (web hosting account vs. dedicated server). You're on the right track in excluding the unfilled inputs and should be able to design a procedure which does just that.

If you're using 5.7, you can find the manual for procedures here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html 
and information on indexing here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

These references basically apply to any version 5.x.

Comment: I forgot to mention the other table, my bad. I mentioned above, I'm sure that will change things, but thanks a ton for your reply and resources!